# How to check if the user is guest in a form

Tags: forms, users

I have a form in a page, so what I want to do is to check wether the user is a guest or a logged user and depending of that add an additional field to a guest, but hide it for the logged user, should this be done in the code of the form or there are some built-in settings for that behaviour?

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate the question. As per the understanding you have to  use this condition to check the user login status.
Since you have to use it in a form, you can implements with `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().`

Use this code to check.

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    echo "Logged In";
}
else {
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

**Edited:**

Example for user_profile_form alter. 
FORM_ID = user_profile_form

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
}
```

To find form id add this in your custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */ 
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  print_r($form_id);
}
```

When you visit the page the form is on, the form_id  will be displayed.

`print_r($form);` , you can see all details of a form, like form ID, field names of a form etc.

Also you can inspect the form and find the form id

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/288/edit" method="post" id="user-profile-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Here id="user-profile-form",
 in order to use it in code replace hiphen (-) with undescore(_)

```
 user-profile-form => user_profile_form
```

Comment: where can I find that FORM_ID in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()?